# Why do I keep getting Influxdb unauthorized access (error 401)

Tags: python, python-3.x, token, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have been trying to follow along the python walkthrough that is provided by influxDB to get familiar with how it works, and just by following the tutorial, I am getting errors, after following each step accordingly. All of the code is from them, yet I keep getting the same error:

```
>>> Request: 'POST https://us-east-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com/api/v2/write?org=PythonTesting&bucket=test1&precision=ns'
>>> Content-Type: text/plain
>>> Accept: application/json
>>> User-Agent: influxdb-client-python/1.37.0
>>> Body: b'census,location=Klamath bees=23i'
<<< Response: 401
<<< Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2023 17:15:22 GMT
<<< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<<< Content-Length: 55
<<< Connection: keep-alive
<<< trace-id: a96c933eaca5845f
<<< trace-sampled: false
<<< x-platform-error-code: unauthorized
<<< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
<<< X-Influxdb-Request-ID: 130ba81a98d7d837641571be3fabc194
<<< X-Influxdb-Build: Cloud
<<< Body: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user G\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\InfluxDB_testing.py", line 51, in <module>
    client.write(database=database, record=point)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client_3\__init__.py", line 106, in write
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client_3\__init__.py", line 104, in write
    self._write_api.write(bucket=database, record=record, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\client\write_api.py", line 378, in write
    results = list(map(write_payload, payloads.items()))
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\client\write_api.py", line 376, in write_payload
    return self._post_write(_async_req, bucket, org, final_string, payload[0])
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\client\write_api.py", line 509, in _post_write
    return self._write_service.post_write(org=org, bucket=bucket, body=body, precision=precision,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\service\write_service.py", line 60, in post_write
    (data) = self.post_write_with_http_info(org, bucket, body, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\service\write_service.py", line 90, in post_write_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\_sync\api_client.py", line 343, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\_sync\api_client.py", line 173, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\_sync\api_client.py", line 388, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\_sync\rest.py", line 311, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MEAfile_parsing\venv\lib\site-packages\influxdb_client\_sync\rest.py", line 261, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 30 Aug 2023 17:15:22 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '55', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'trace-id': 'a96c933eaca5845f', 'trace-sampled': 'false', 'x-platform-error-code': 'unauthorized', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains', 'X-Influxdb-Request-ID': '130ba81a98d7d837641571be3fabc194', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'Cloud'})
HTTP response body: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried resetting the access token environment variable multiple times with full access to everything, but nothing changed. all of the variables such as host and org were set by the tutorial and configured by it for my particular set up. if you wish to see the tutorial here it requires a sign up here: https://cloud2.influxdata.com/signup

yes I also have all of the dependencies installed. here is the code with some edits to the links and variables for privacy reasons:

```
import os, time
from influxdb_client_3 import InfluxDBClient3, Point

token = os.environ.get("INFLUXDB_TOKEN") # this I set in as an environmental variable from an all #access token that is given via the tutorial
org = "PythonTesting"
host = "myhost" # host link is given to me and provided by aws

client = InfluxDBClient3(host=host, token=token, org=org, debug=True)

database="test1"

data = {
  "point1": {
    "location": "Klamath",
    "species": "bees",
    "count": 23,
  },
  "point2": {
    "location": "Portland",
    "species": "ants",
    "count": 30,
  },
  "point3": {
    "location": "Klamath",
    "species": "bees",
    "count": 28,
  },
  "point4": {
    "location": "Portland",
    "species": "ants",
    "count": 32,
  },
  "point5": {
    "location": "Klamath",
    "species": "bees",
    "count": 29,
  },
  "point6": {
    "location": "Portland",
    "species": "ants",
    "count": 40,
  },
}

for key in data:
  point = (
    Point("census")
    .tag("location", data[key]["location"])
    .field(data[key]["species"], data[key]["count"])
  )
  client.write(database=database, record=point)
  time.sleep(1) # separate points by 1 second

print("Complete. Return to the InfluxDB UI.")
```

again you can follow along the tutorial and see that this is from influxdb's instructional intro. This is supposed to be a five minute set up so I don't know why this is happening. I see there is many other stack overflow pages with similar questions, none of which are fully answered or even acknowledged. I hope that this can be solved so others can resolve the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what was wrong in my case, I went through and triple checked everything, and realized, maybe the token is not be recognized correctly.

After doing so I printed out the token value and it returned null. That was odd as I had set it in the `cmd` as a `system environment variable`. The problem was that my IDE (pycharm in my case) did not recognize the environmental variables by default, So I had to go and add them manually.

Sure enough after that small change and hours of grief, it worked and the data went through.

Comment: That pain would have been avoided by using `os.environ["INFLUXDB_TOKEN"]` as it would have thrown a KeyError instead of `.get()` assigning `None` to `token`.